# Select rows with alternate ordered field from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Given a *students_exam_rooms* table:

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| student_id | room_id | seat_no |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |      30 |    1001 |
|          2 |      30 |    1002 |
|          3 |      31 |    2001 |
|          4 |      32 |    2002 |
|          5 |      33 |    3001 |
|          6 |      33 |    3002 |
|          7 |      34 |    4001 |
|          8 |      34 |    4002 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

And *students_tbl*:

```
+------------+-------------+------+
| student_id | studen_name | year |
+------------+-------------+------+
|          1 | Eric        |    1 |
|          2 | Mustafa     |    1 |
|          3 | Michael     |    2 |
|          4 | Andy        |    2 |
|          5 | Rafael      |    3 |
|          6 | Mark        |    3 |
|          7 | Jack        |    4 |
|          8 | peter       |    4 |
+------------+-------------+------+
```

How can I select from *students_exam_rooms* ordering by *students_tbl.year* but with one after one like this:

```
+--------------+------+
| student_name | year |
+--------------+------+
| Eric         |    1 |
| Michael      |    2 |
| Rafael       |    3 |
| Jack         |    4 |
| Mustafa      |    1 |
| Andy         |    2 |
| Mark         |    3 |
| Peter        |    4 |
+--------------+------+
```

Comment: Please can you explain what you mean by "one after one"?   I can't really see the logical connection between the tables you mentioned and the resultant order which makes advising pretty tricky.

Comment: sorry for bad English ,, I mean if I select with order by year the result will be students with years 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 , but I want the order shown in the results

Comment: You want to order by the "occurrence-count" of the year then the year? By that I mean all the first-occurrences of all years first, sorted by year, then all second-occurrences of all years also sorted by year, and so on?

Comment: It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to order by the "occurrence-count" of the year then the year, e.g. all the first-occurrences of all years first, sorted by year, then all second-occurrences of all years also sorted by year, and so on. That would be a perfect case for emulating other RDBMS' analytic / windowing functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        s.studen_name,
        s.year,
        ser.*,
        (
            select 1 + count(*)
            from students_tbl s2
            where s.year = s2.year
                and s.student_id > s2.student_id
        ) rank
    from students_tbl s
        JOIN students_exam_rooms ser
            ON s.student_id = ser.student_id
) i_dont_really_want_to_name_this
order by rank, year
```

Here it is against a slightly tweaked version of JW's fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27c91/1

[Emulating Analytic (AKA Ranking) Functions with MySQL](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html) is a good article that gives more background and explanation.

Comment: Thanks , that's it , I know it's a bit confusing my question and my English as well

Answer (score 1):

try any of these below:

```
SELECT  a.studen_name, a.year
FROM    students_tbl a
        INNER JOIN students_exam_rooms b
          ON a.student_id = b.student_id
ORDER   BY  REVERSE(b.seat_no),
            a.year
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c9b/2)

by using `Modulo`

```
SELECT  a.studen_name, a.year
FROM    students_tbl a
        INNER JOIN students_exam_rooms b
          ON a.student_id = b.student_id
ORDER   BY CASE WHEN MOD(b.seat_no, 2) <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
            a.year
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30c9b/1)

Comment: first of thx J W , you are always here ,  but I want the results without any relation to seat_no , check this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5c24/1   when I changed the seat_no randomly ,

Comment: so what is the basis for sorting the records?

Comment: based on year having the result as I mentioned 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 not 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're trying to sort first by seat and then by year. Looking at your `students_exam_rooms` table, it looks like you started with a simple seat number and prepended `year * 1000`. So, if we omit the year, it looks like this:

```
> select * from fixed_students_exam_rooms;
+------------+---------+---------+
| student_id | room_id | seat_no |
+------------+---------+---------+
|          1 |      30 |       1 |
|          2 |      30 |       2 |
|          3 |      31 |       1 |
|          4 |      32 |       2 |
|          5 |      33 |       1 |
|          6 |      33 |       2 |
|          7 |      34 |       1 |
|          8 |      34 |       2 |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

And if you had *that* table, your query is simple:

```
select
  student_name, year

from
  modified_student_exame_rooms
  left join students_tbl using (student_id)

order by
  seat_no, year
;
```

Using the table *as you currently have it*, it's only slightly more complicated, assuming the "core seat number" doesn't excede 999.

```
select
  student_name, year

from
  modified_student_exame_rooms
  left join students_tbl using (student_id)

order by
  convert(substr(seat_no, 2), unsigned),
  year
;
```